# How to switch Tab programmatically from child Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

Well I have my app basic structure like below

```
Tabs
 SherlockFragmentActivity(Has Fragments One, Two, Three, Four)
 |
 |-->|SherlockFragment_one (Has Chiled Fragments A, B, C Using Viewpager)
 |   |
 |   |-->SherlockFragment_one_A
 |   |-->SherlockFragment_one_B
 |   |-->SherlockFragment_one_C
 |
 |
 |-->SherlockFragment_two
 |-->SherlockFragment_three
 |-->SherlockFragment_Four
```

Here is the Image

[image]

Look at the Image my child Fragment (Say SherlockFragment_one_A) has a Listview. I want to switch the Tab on any Item Click of this Listview.

For code of my app structure. see my Accepted Answer [android-layout-actionbarsherlock-tabs-viewpagerindicator-on-1st-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704277/android-layout-actionbarsherlock-tabs-viewpagerindicator-on-1st-tab).

**Question:** Is this possible to switch the tab progrmatically from child fragment

here is my code of my child fragment having the listview

```
   package fragment.overview;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.example.myappstructure.R;

public class OverView_Nearby_events extends SherlockFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_nearby_evets, container,
                false);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter());

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        // **********Switch Tab over Here**********//

        // I tried this. but not any success.
        //ActionBar.Tab host = (ActionBar.Tab) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
        //host.setCurrentTab(3);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.overview_nearby_events_listitems, parent, false);

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
*Temporary Solution*

```
if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 11) {
        android.app.ActionBar.Tab eventTab = getActivity().getActionBar()
                .getTabAt(3);
        getActivity().getActionBar().selectTab(eventTab);
    }
```

but this is valid upto API level 11, I Have used the support library. How to do make this work in all android versions i.e upto API level 8 min froyo?

Comment: create method  setCurrenttab(tabIndex) in parent activity and from child fragment call ((ParentActivityName)getActivity()).setCurrentTab(index);

Comment: You mean I should create method in my SherlockFragmentActivity(Has Fragments One, Two, Three, Four) ??

Comment: Yes n then change tabs from there

Comment: why the commonsware tag ?

Comment: Oops sorry for that. I will edit it soon

Comment: @jay see my edit. But Im not getting your solution. can you paste a code snippt of what you have suggested. thanks

Comment: Are u using tabHost for tabs ?

Comment: @jay No Im using the actionbar tabs see my activity's code in my accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704277/android-layout-actionbarsherlock-tabs-viewpagerindicator-on-1st-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 11) {
        android.app.ActionBar.Tab eventTab = getActivity().getActionBar()
                .getTabAt(3);
        getActivity().getActionBar().selectTab(eventTab);
    }
```

but this is valid upto API level 11, I Have used the support library. How to do make this work in all android versions i.e upto API level 8 min froyo? I don't know about this. :)